# Typescript - What type of function is it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function

Could someone tell me:

1. what type of function is it? Link to deep description?
2. how to call that providing both name and value params

```
private someFunction = (name: string) => (value: number): void => {
    //Do some stuff there
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application . To call `someFunction('foo')(123)`

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a function that returns another function. Both using the arrow function syntax.

This is the same but then not in the shortened format

```
const someFunction = (name: string) => {
  return (value: number) => {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(value);
  };
}

const logNameHenryAndValue = someFunction("Henry");
logNameHenryAndValue(2);
```

Once `logNameHenryAndValue(2)` is run it should log

```
- "Henry"
- 2
```

This is called currying and can be used to compose functions: [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Answer (score 1):

The type of function is:

```
type ReturnFuction = (name:string) => ((value: number) => void);
```

This pattern called [currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

```
const name = "a";
const value = 5;
someFunction(name)(value);
```

Full example:

```
type ReturnFuction = (name:string) => ((value: number) => void);

const someFunction:ReturnFuction = (name) => (value) => {
    //Do some stuff there
};

// someFunction returns a function (number => void)
const foo = someFunction("hello");

// function call (number => void)
foo(5);
```